# triggers in update panel - asp.net

Tags: asp.net, triggers, updatepanel

Can i place more than one triggers for a single update panel? Is it possible to give multiple triggers for an update panel. Is there anything that i should take care if i am using multiple triggers( if it possible) ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. AFAIK, there is no harm in doing it. When you create multiple triggers, you are simply choosing to update your UpdatePanel when any one of the triggers fire.